# DataGrid NewItemPlaceholderPosition lost when ItemsSource changed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two DataGrids above one another, and selecting a row in the top grid, `OrdersGrid`, displays some details in the bottom grid, `DetailsGrid`, about the selected row from `OrdersGrid`.

I would like the `NewItemPlaceholderPosition` to be `AtBeginning` for both grids. This is easy enough for `OrdersGrid` because I can just set it in my `UserControl` subclass constructor:

```
((IEditableCollectionView)OrdersGrid.Items).NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
```

But the problem is that the `ItemsSource` for `DetailsGrid` is a member of the currently selected item in `OrdersGrid`.

If I set `NewItemPlaceholderPosition` for `DetailsGrid` as above then it works until I click on a new row in `OrdersGrid` when it goes back to the default of being at the bottom since `DetailsGrid` reloads from its new `ItemsSource`.

The `ItemsSource` for `OrdersGrid` is an `ObservableCollection` called `Orders`, which contains Objects of type `Order`, and the `ItemsSource` for `DetailsGrid` is `Order.Details`, also an `ObservableCollection`, for the current `Order`.

I'm thinking I want something like an `ItemsSourceChanged` event for `DetailsGrid`, but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or even how to go about this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the following to my `UserControl` subclass constructor:

```
((IEditableCollectionView)DetailsGrid.Items).NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;

var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(DataGrid));
if (dpd != null)
{
    dpd.AddValueChanged(DetailsGrid, DetailsSourceChanged);
}
```

with the `DetailsSourceChanged` method defined as followed:

```
private void DetailsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailsGrid.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        ((IEditableCollectionView)DetailsGrid.Items).NewItemPlaceholderPosition = NewItemPlaceholderPosition.AtBeginning;
    }
}
```